# Value is set to 0 but still returns as NaN

Tags: javascript, html

Hey all making a mini golf score card for my work and I want the inputs value to automatically be set to 0 if input is left blank. I thought that declaring the variables as 0 would solve that issue but if all inputs are left blank it comes up with "NaN" instead of 0. I'm pretty new to javascript

```
function p1Score() {
    h1p1, h2p1, h3p1, h4p1, h5p1, h6p1, h7p1, h8p1, h9p1, h10p1, h11p1, h12p1, h13p1, h14p1, h15p1, h16p1, h17p1, h18p1 = 0
    var  h1p1 = document.getElementById( "h1p1").valueAsNumber;
    var  h2p1 = document.getElementById( "h2p1").valueAsNumber;
    var  h3p1 = document.getElementById( "h3p1").valueAsNumber;
    var  h4p1 = document.getElementById( "h4p1").valueAsNumber;
    var  h5p1 = document.getElementById( "h5p1").valueAsNumber;
    var  h6p1 = document.getElementById( "h6p1").valueAsNumber;
    var  h7p1 = document.getElementById( "h7p1").valueAsNumber;
    var  h8p1 = document.getElementById( "h8p1").valueAsNumber;
    var  h9p1 = document.getElementById( "h9p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h10p1 = document.getElementById("h10p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h11p1 = document.getElementById("h11p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h12p1 = document.getElementById("h12p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h13p1 = document.getElementById("h13p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h14p1 = document.getElementById("h14p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h15p1 = document.getElementById("h15p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h16p1 = document.getElementById("h16p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h17p1 = document.getElementById("h17p1").valueAsNumber;
    var h18p1 = document.getElementById("h18p1").valueAsNumber;
    var totalscorep1 = h1p1 + h2p1 + h3p1 + h4p1 + h5p1 + h6p1 + h7p1 + h8p1 + h9p1 + h10p1 + h11p1 + h12p1 + h13p1 + h14p1 + h15p1 + h16p1 + h17p1 + h18p1;
    document.getElementById("p1total").innerHTML = totalscorep1;
}
```

Comment: you are only setting the value of h18p1 to 0

Comment: @ControlAltDel but then overriding all the declarations with the `.valueAsNumber` from various elements.

Comment: Show the HTML of the inputs you are getting.  If they aren't `type="number"` that is probably why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not repeating yourself 18 times. The problem seems to be that some of your values are NaN. Try this to see which ones:

```
function p1Score() {
  var totalScore = 0;
  for(var i = 1; i <= 18; i++) {
    var key = "h" + i + "p1";
    var value = document.getElementById(key).valueAsNumber;
    if (isNaN(value) {
      console.log(key + " is NaN")
    }
    else {
      totalScore += value;
    }
  }
  document.getElementById("p1total").innerHTML = totalScore;
}
```